# How to solve error Invalid model in action definition

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8

I'm trying to add a new submenu with my custom module at the bottom of the "hr.contract" menus but it shows an error. Then I tried to run the example shown in the odoo documentation, the same error is displayed. I do not understand why or how it will be corrected. Any idea for help please?

payroll_per_hour_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<openerp>
<data>
  <record id="action_payroll_hour_form" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="res_model">hr.contract</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="name">Grille de prix d'heure</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window </field>
    </record>
   <menuitem id="menu_payroll_per_hour" name="Grille d'heure" parent="hr.menu_hr_main"  action="action_payroll_hour_form" sequence="10"/>

</data>
</openerp>
```

traceback

```
ParseError: "ValidateError
Champ(s)  `res_model, src_model` en erreur vis \xe0 vis de la contrainte : Mod\xe8le non valide dans la d\xe9finition de l'action.  " while parsing file:///d:/projet_odoo/odoo-8.0-20171009/openerp/addons/payroll_per_hour/views/payroll_per_hour_view.xml:5, near
 <record id="action_payroll_hour_form" model="ir.actions.act_window">
              <field name="res_model">hr.contract</field>
             <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="name">Grille de prix d'heure</field>
             <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window </field>
        </record>
```

**openerp**.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

{
'name': 'Paiement par heure',
'version': '8.0',
'summary': '',
'description': """

""",
'author': '',
'images': [],
'depends': [],
'data': [ 'views/payroll_per_hour_view.xml',],
'demo': [],
'test': [],
'installable': True,
'auto_install': False,

 }
 # vim:expandtab:smartindent:tabstop=4:softtabstop=4:shiftwidth=4:
```

Comment: Can you show the manifest file ?

Comment: Ok , Check  my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add dependence to `hr_contract` module to be able to use its features.

```
'depends': ['hr_contract'],
```